# ruby 1.8.7 multithread mail 'uninitialized constant (NameError)'

Tags: ruby, nameerror

My script sends emails for list of users. I need multithreading because error in 1 address crashes all app. This is my implementation:

```
  require 'thread'
  <...>
  lock = Mutex.new
  lock.synchronize {
    @model.certs.each{ |user|
      @threads << Thread.new(user) { |data|
      to = "#{data['name']} #{data['surname']} <#{data['email']}>"
      subject = '<Subject>'
      body = "<Body>"
      view = View.new()
      view.to = to
      view.body = body
      view.subject = subject
      view.attachment = ''
      view.sendMessage()
      @model.sended(data['email'])
      }
    }
  }

  @threads.each { |t|
    begin
      t.join
    rescue => err
      $log.fatal(err)
    end
  }
```

`view.sendMessage` consists:

```
require 'mail'
require 'net/smtp'
<...>
smtp = Net::SMTP.start(@mailserver)
mail = Mail.new()
mail.from = @from
mail.to = @to
mail.subject = @subject
mail.body = @body
if !@attachment.empty?
  mail.add_file @attachment
end
mail.delivery_method :smtp_connection, {
  :connection => smtp
}
mail.deliver
```

And **sometimes** it gives such mistakes as:

```
uninitialized constant Mail::Field::FromField (NameError)
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/field.rb:189:in `new_field'
```

or

```
uninitialized constant Mail::CommonAddress::AddressList (NameError)
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/fields/common/common_address.rb:9:in `parse'
```

I have no idea, how it can be fixed. Mutex adding has no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FrederickCheung is right about require in threads. Aditionally, do you really need threads? What is wrong with:

```
emails.each do |mail|
  begin
    mail.deliver
  rescue TheCorrectExceptionForInvalidEmails
    puts "invalid e-mail: x"
    method_to_remove_invalid_email_from_database
  end
end
```

Even if you let an empty block for the rescue, in an invalid e-mail, it will jump and continue executing.

Comment: Even if you don't implement the method to handle the bad email, you can still continue sending. Check my edit

Comment: It looks like my old code version, which crashes whole app. I'll try this solution tomorrow again. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Require isn't threadsafe in ruby. You should ensure that everything you need is already required before you start your threads.

In addition your mutex isn't currently doing anything. While multi threading can be a good fit for an activity like sending email that is probably dominated by network latency, I wouldn't say error handling is a reason to use multithreading (if anything it makes it harder).

Comment: IMHO require-error must be constantly not periodical as it is in my case. Ok, I'll read more about mutex. And what good practice I should use to handle such type of error instead of threading?

Comment: With threads there are race conditions in require - thread 1 is partway through loading the library, so thread 2 ends up using partially loaded library